# Python script hung up on return statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, file

I wrote a script to open, read, and return numpy arrays saved in .npy files on my local machine. I have done this before many times, but for some reason, my script this time seems to be hung up on the return statement. It opens, reads, and closes the npy file, saving it on a local variable, but then when the function is supposed to return the array, it just gets hung up and I have to close the program. I've verified that it gets hung up on the return statement by debugging in VSCode and stepping through each line.

```
if label == 0 or label == 1:
    print('Opening Label 1 arrays..')
    with open(f'npys\\labels\\label1.npy', 'rb') as f:
        label1 = np.load(f)
    if label == 1:
        return label1

if label == 0 or label == 2:
    print('Opening Label 2 centroid arrays..')
    with open(f'npys\\labels\\label2.npy', 'rb') as f:
        label2 = np.load(f)
    if label == 2:
        return label2

if label == 0 or label == 3:
    print('Opening Label 3 arrays..')
    with open(f'npys\\labels\\label3.npy', 'rb') as f:
        label3 = np.load(f)
    if label == 3:
        return label3

if label == 0 or label == 4:
    print('Opening Label 4 arrays..')
    with open(f'npys\\labels\\label4.npy', 'rb') as f:
        label4 = np.load(f)
    if label == 4:
        return label4

return label1, label2, label3, label4
```

Honestly, I'm lost as to what to do. I have moved variables around, but that's about it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which return statement are you talking about? Also why is there a return statement at the end of this code, what is that supposed to be for?

Comment: If this is a function please indent appropriately and include the entire function.

Comment: @JesseSealand I'm guessing that this is the body of something like `def readlabels(numlabel):`, which either returns the contents of a single file (if the argument is 1-4) or returns all of them in a tuple (if the argument is 0). Regarding further diagnostics: can you use the local variables like `label1` _before_ you return them, i.e., print some values directly after reading the file? Maybe the files have been corrupted or there is some kind of version conflict, does it also fail if you save a new small `.npy` file and try to read and return that?

Comment: I'm thinking pretty much the same thing. Probably needs to define the labels up front before they go into the routines to read numpy files so they exist by the time you get the final return statement.

Answer (score -2):

Solved! There's no problem with this block of code, there was a problem with the line that called this function!

So basically I am trying to get the labels and split them into chunks, and the line that was hung up was as follows:

```
self.labels = torch.tensor(np.split(get_labels(label_num), num_frames))
```

I solved this by changing it to the following:

```
self.labels = torch.from_numpy(np.array(np.split(get_labels(label_num), num_frames)))
```

As np.split returns a list of np arrays, I imagine the heterogenous list tripped up pytorch, and it was taking a while to convert it into a tensor.